# Why IsAssignableFrom return false when comparing a nullable against an interface?

Tags: c#, types

The following call in C# returns false :

```
typeof(IComparable).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(DateTime?))
```

However, the following line is perfectly valid :

```
IComparable comparable = (DateTime?)DateTime.Now;
```

Why is it so ?

Is it because nullable types are backed using `Nullable<T>`and the fact the first generic argument implements an interface does not imply that the Nullable class also implement that interface ? (eg : `List<Foo>` does not implement interfaces that `Foo` implement)

EDIT : 
I think the line above compile because when boxing an nullable type, only the underlying type is boxed as explained here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228597.aspx

Comment: The interesting question is why your second line compiles even if `Nullable<T>` doesn't implement `IComparable`

Comment: I should probably rewrote the question.

Comment: The link you've provided explains it already pretty well and even shows an example with a nullable that can be assigned to `IConvertible`. So the reason is, if a nullable has a value it will be boxed to the underlying type `T`, not to the nullable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason for this behaviour is that `IsAssignableFrom()` does not consider the special boxing conversions that the compiler emits for conversion of nullable types.

Note that you don't actually need the cast in your question.

Instead of

```
 IComparable comparable = (DateTime?)DateTime.Now;
```

you can write:

```
DateTime? test = DateTime.Now;
IComparable comparable = test;
```

The first of those lines compiles because `Nullable<T>` provides an implicit conversion operator:

```
public static implicit operator Nullable<T> (
    T value
)
```

The second line causes the compiler to emit a box instruction:

```
L_000e: box [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<valuetype [mscorlib]System.DateTime>
```

This boxing operation is covered by section 6.1.7 of the C# language spec, **Boxing conversions** (this covers boxing conversions for nullable types specifically), which states:

> A boxing conversion permits a value-type to be implicitly converted to
>   a reference type. A boxing conversion exists from any
>   non-nullable-value-type to object and dynamic, to System.ValueType ***and
>   to any interface-type implemented by the non-nullable-value-type***.
>   Furthermore an enum-type can be converted to the type System.Enum.
>
> A boxing conversion exists from a nullable-type to a reference type, if
>   and only if a boxing conversion exists from the underlying
>   non-nullable-value-type to the reference type.
>
> A value type has a boxing conversion to an interface type I if it has a boxing conversion
>   to an interface type I0 and I0 has an identity conversion to I.
>
> A value type has a boxing conversion to an interface type I if it has a
>   boxing conversion to an interface or delegate type I0 and I0 is
>   variance-convertible (§13.1.3.2) to I.
>
> Boxing a value of a non-nullable-value-type consists of allocating an object instance and
>   copying the value-type value into that instance. A struct can be boxed
>   to the type System.ValueType, since that is a base class for all
>   structs (§11.3.2).

This is what is giving rise to the boxing operation above. I've bolded and italicised the most pertinent point.

Also see this link (supplied by the OP): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228597.aspx

Comment: But why is it used when i don't cast to `T` of a `Nullable<T>` but when i assign it to an interface that `T` implements? So it does answer a question why i can use `DateTime.Now` and assign it to a `DateTime?` variable, but it doesn't explain(?) why i can assign a nullable to an interface that `T` implements.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Indeed, and that is a different question. :)

Comment: It's not really a different question because your answer would explain it only if OP would try: `typeof(DateTime).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(DateTime?));`(which would also return `false`). But actually he's trying to assign it to `IComparable`

Comment: Actually OP answered this question already with [the link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228597.aspx) he has provided. Nullables with a value will be boxed to the underlying type `T` not to the nullable.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I've added a reference to the relevant part of the C# standard; I'll also add the OP's link for completeness.

Answer (score 3):

Nullables are special.

```
object boxedNullable = new decimal?(42M);

Console.WriteLine(boxedNullable.GetType().Name); // Decimal
```

When you box  a nullable value, what you actually do is box the underlying value, not the nullable. So `default(decimal?)` will give you just `null` (rather than a "no-value nullable"), and `new decimal?(42M)` will give you a boxed `decimal`.

When you cast a value type to an interface, it *must* be boxed - so your second line actually changes the nullable to a boxed `DateTime`. `DateTime?` doesn't implement `IComparable`, but `DateTime` does - and that's what you're ultimately casting to the interface, because the value type must be boxed first.

This is defined in the ECMA specification, `I.8.2.4 Boxing and unboxing of values`:

> All value types have an operation called box. Boxing a value of any value type produces its boxed value; i.e., a value of the corresponding boxed type containing a bitwise copy of the original value. If the value type is a nullable type—defined as an instantiation of the value type `System.Nullable<T>`—the result is a null reference or bitwise copy of its Value property of type T, depending on its HasValue property (false and true, respectively). All boxed types have an operation called unbox, which results in a managed pointer to the bit representation of the value.

Your best bet is to use either `x is IComparable` or `x as IComparable` to find if some type implements `IComparable`; using reflection exposes you to a lot of the tiny little quirks of both .NET and C# (and whatever other language the guy who wrote the code used).